# Which of the following is isomorphic to the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

- $C_2 \times C_2 \times C_6$
- $C_2 \times C_{12}$
- $C_{24}$

The group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{35}$ is $\mathbb{Z}_{35}^\#=               
  \left\{ 1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11,12,13,16,17,18,19,22,23,24,26,27,29,31,32,33,34 \right\}$.

Comment: what have you tried ? Why makes the three possibilities you gave non-isomorphic ?

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{Z}_{35} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{7}$, by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Chinese Remainder Theorem, so $C_4 \times C_6$. Then as pointed out below, you can write as $C_2 \times C_3 \times C_4 $ and thence as $C_2 \times C_{12}$, clumsy though it is.

Comment: With generators 17 and -1